# Vakil's FOAG Exercise 1.2.B.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

From the text:

If $A$ is an object in a category $\mathcal{C}$, show that the invertible elements of Mor($\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{A}$) form a group (called the automorphism group of $\mathcal{A}$, denoted Aut($\mathcal{A}$)). Show that two isomorphic objects have isomorphic automorphism groups.

(For readers with a topological background: if $X$ is a topological space, then the fundamental groupoid is the category where the objects are points of $X$, and the morphisms $x\to y$ are paths from $x$ to $y$, up to homotopy. Then the automorphism group of $x_0$ is the (pointed) fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. **In the case where $X$ is connected, and $\pi_1(X)$ is not abelian, this illustrates the fact that for a connected groupoid - whose definition you can guess - the automorphism groups of the objects are all isomorphic, but not canonically isomorphic.)**

Now, I understand everything up the final bolded sentence. Here are couple questions I have:

1. My guess is that a connected groupoid is a groupoid where every pair of objects has a morphism between them. I would think this would correspond with a path-connected topological space since we are talking about paths between each point. Given this, why is $X$ assumed to be connected rather than path-connected? I know there examples of connected spaces that are not path-connected such as the topologist's sine curve. In this case wouldn't the fundamental groupoid of the space not be connected?
2. As I understand it, in a path-connected space $\pi_1(X)$ refers to $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ for any $x_0\in X$ since these pointed fundamental groups are all isomorphic. Therefore, when we say $\pi_1(X)$ is not abelian we are really saying $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is not abelian for any $x_0\in X$. If the space is path-connected it would make sense but if it is only assumed to be connected only I'm not sure what $\pi_1(X)$ would refer to.

This could just be a simple misunderstanding of certain wording and resulting implications so any clarification would be appreciated. I think the issue really boils down to connectedness vs. path-connectedness in this context. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your guess about what it means for a groupoid to be connected is exactly right and your concerns are quite justified. The author should have written "in the case where $X$ is path-connected" rather than "in the case where $X$ is connected".

For point (1), the topologist's sine curve $C$ is connected but not path-connected. Its fundamental groupoid is not connected: it has objects in one-to-one correspondence with the half-open interval $[0, 1)$ with a morphism between any two points that are either both non-zero or are both zero. So there is no path between $0$ and any non-zero element in the fundamental groupoid.

For point (2), take a space $X$ and a point $x_0\in X$, such that $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ is not abelian and form the identification space $Y = (X \cup C) / (x_0 \sim 0)$, (where I am viewing $C$ as a subspace of $\Bbb{C}$ that is the graph of a certain function $[0, 1] \to [-1, 1]$). Then $\pi_1(Y, x_0)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ and hence is not abelian, but $\pi_1(Y, 1)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(C, 1)$ which is the trivial group with just $1$ element and hence is abelian. So, in $Y$, it does not make sense to talk about $\pi_1(Y)$: you have to  specify a base point.

Comment: In fact, if you take the topologist's sine curve and then quotient out by $(0, -1) \sim (0, 1)$, then you end up with a connected space where different base points give nonisomorphic $\pi_1$ groups (the points on the sine curve part giving $\pi_1(X, x_0) = 0$ and the points on the vertical segment - which becomes a circle under the quotient - giving $\pi_1(X, x_0) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: @DanielSchepler: yes, that's another nice counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, a groupoid is connected if every pair of objects has a morphism between them.

The phrase "In the case where $X$ is connected" is definitely misleading, but I wouldn't say it is wrong. In fact, the groupoid $X$ is connected if and only if the topological space $X$ is path-connected. Thus it would be better to write

- In the case where the groupoid $X$ is connected

or

- In the case where the topological space $X$ is path-connected

You are also right that in a path-connected space $\pi_1(X)$ refers to $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ for any $x_0\in X$ since these pointed fundamental groups are all isomorphic.

Strictly speaking the notation $\pi_1(X)$ does not make sense, but one could understand it as the **set of isomorphic groups** $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ with $x_0 \in X$. However, for path-connected spaces $X$ it is common use to say things like

- the fundamental group of $X$ is abelian, finite, etc.
- $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian, finite, etc.

Actually it is a slight abuse of notation to speak about **the** fundamental group of $X$ or to write $\pi_1(X)$. The justification is that the attributes "abelian, finite, ..." occurring here apply indeed to isomorphism classes of groups.

Anyway, for spaces $X$ which are not path-connected it is definitely wrong to write $\pi_1(X)$.